# Issue with Java varargs and generics in abstract classes

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I'm playing with some functional like programming.  And having issues with some pretty deeply nested generics.  Here's my SCCE that fails, with an abstract class involved:

```
public abstract class FooGen<IN, OUT> {

    OUT fn2(IN in1, IN in2) {  // clever? try at a lazy way, just call the varargs version
      return fnN(in1, in2);
   }

   abstract OUT fnN(IN...ins); // subclasses implement this

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      FooGen<Number, Number> foogen = new FooGen<Number, Number>() {   
         @Override Number fnN(Number... numbers) { 
            return numbers[0];
         }
      };

      System.out.println(foogen.fn2(1.2, 3.4));           
   }
}
```

This dies with a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Number;
```

However, for a *non-abstract* FooGen, it works fine:

```
public class FooGen<IN, OUT> {

      OUT fn2(IN g1, IN g2) { 
         return fnN(g1, g2); 
      }

      OUT fnN(IN...gs) {
         return (OUT)gs[0];
      }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      FooGen<Number,Number> foogen = new FooGen<Number,Number>();
      System.out.println(foogen.fn2(1.2, 3.4)); 
   }
}
```

This prints 1.2.  Ideas?  It seems like somewhere Java has lost track of the generics.  This is pushing the limits of my generics knowledge.  :-)

**(Added in response to answers)**

First, thanks for the upvotes, and to Paul and Daemon for their helpful answers.

Still wondering why it works as Numbers in the 2nd version, I had an insight.  As a Thought Experiment, let's add a `.doubleValue()` somewhere.  *You can't.*  In the code itself the variables are INs, not Numbers.  And in the `main()` it's merely declaring the type, `FooGen<Number,Number>` but there's no place there to add code.

In Version #2, it really isn't "working" as *Numbers*.  Internally, with erasure, everything is Objects, as explained by Paul and Daemon, and, looking back sheepishly, well understood by myself.  Basically, in this complex example, I got overexcited and mislead by the `<Number>` declaration.

Don't think I'll bother with a workaround.  The whole idea was to be lazy.  :-)  For efficiency I created parallel interfaces and code that take primitive doubles (and ints), and there this trick works just fine.

Comment: No.  Mostly yes, but you could be counting words, comparing Dates etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Varargs parameters are first and foremost arrays. So without the syntactic sugar, your code would look like the following:

```
OUT fn2(IN in1, IN in2) {
    return fnN(new IN[] {in1, in2});
}

abstract OUT fnN(IN[] ins);
```

Except `new IN[]` would not be legal because [arrays of type parameters cannot be instantiated](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ202), due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). An array needs to know its component type, but `IN` has been *erased* to its upper bound, `Object`, at runtime.

The varargs invocation hides this issue unfortunately, and at runtime you have the equivalent of `fnN(new Object[] {in1, in2})`, whereas `fnN` has been overriden to take a `Number[]`.

> However, for a *non-abstract* FooGen, it works fine

This is because by instantiating `FooGen` directly, you haven't overridden `fnN`. Thus it accepts an `Object[]` at runtime and no `ClassCastException` occurs.

For example, this will fail even if `FooGen` isn't `abstract`:

```
FooGen<Number, Number> foogen = new FooGen<Number, Number>() {
    @Override
    Number fnN(Number... gs) {
        return super.fnN(gs);
    }
};
System.out.println(foogen.fn2(1.2, 3.4));
```

So you can see that it really isn't related to the abstractness of `FooGen`, but to whether `fnN` gets overridden with a narrowed argument type.

**SOLUTION**

There are no easy workarounds. One idea is to have `fnN` take a `List<? extends IN>` instead:

```
OUT fn2(IN in1, IN in2) {
    //safe because the array won't be exposed outside the list
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<IN> ins = Arrays.asList(in1, in2);
    return fnN(ins);
}

abstract OUT fnN(List<? extends IN> ins);
```

If you wanted to keep the varargs support, you could treat this method as an implementation detail and delegate to it:

```
abstract OUT fnNImpl(List<? extends IN> ins);

public final OUT fnN(IN... ins) {
    return fnNImpl(Arrays.asList(ins));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the delegate workaround. I hadn't considered that kind of approach.

Comment: But why does the non-abstract version #2 work?  I think it would have the same issues.

Comment: To followup, once I encountered the error and suspected it involved Java's non-generic arrays, (thanks for the detailed explanation)  that left me wondering how the second version ever worked.

Answer (score 2):

This `ClassCastException` occurs due to a feature of Java called "type erasure". Type erasure occurs when generics are compiled. Since the Java compiler cannot know the type of a generic class at run-time, it will instead compile the generic objects as instances of `Object`.

In your code, when `FooGen` is compiled, `fnN(IN... ins)` receives a parameter of type `Object[]`. The `ClassCastException` occurs when you then attempt to down-cast one of these Objects to your generic type `OUT`.

This isn't even mentioning the fact that creation of such "generic arrays" is prohibited in Java regardless.

Here is a quote from [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ300):

> Here is another example that illustrates the potential danger of
>   ignoring the warning issued regarding array construction in
>   conjunction with variable argument lists.

```
Example (of a varargs method and its invocation):

public final class Test {  
        static <T> T[] method_1(T t1, T t2) { 
            return method_2(t1, t2);                      // unchecked warning 
        } 
        static <T> T[] method_2( T... args) { 
            return args; 
        } 
        public static void main(String... args) { 
            String[] strings = method_1("bad", "karma");  // ClassCastException 
        } 
} 

warning: [unchecked] unchecked generic array creation of type T[] for
varargs parameter 
            return method_2(t1, t2);
                           ^
```

> In this example the first method calls a second method and the second
>   method takes a variable argument list.  In order to invoke the varargs
>   method the compiler creates an array and passes it to the method. In
>   this example the array to be created is an array of type T[] , that
>   is, an array whose component type is a type parameter.  Creation of
>   such arrays is prohibited in Java and you would receive an error
>   message if you tried to create such an array yourself.